# Hosting a website using server software

Tags: eclipse, apache, server, web-hosting

**How can i host a website through my computer using server softwares?**
*I tried to host a website through my own computer using apache tomcat server but it didnt work* ( please briefly explain every point )

Answer (score 0):

The main issue that you need to deal with is getting the clients to your computer.

Yes, it is possible and yes I have done it, albeit a while ago.

1. You need to see if you can browse to your computers website from another device on your network, this will ensure that apache is working. Try another computer/laptop/tablet/whatever to see if this site reachable by other computers using the IP Address and possibly port number. If you cannot get to the site, there are settings in apache to deny certain ip's, google it to get the exact steps for your version. If it works, move on to step 2.

*You will need a static IP Address to ensure that all further steps stay working, google this if you are not sure how to do it*

2. You need to have the external IP address of your router(whatsmyip.org) or use Dynamic DNS to route traffic from an address to your ip and there are services that allow this. I can recommend no-ip.com - This is all assuming that you have access to the router.
3. You would be required to set up port forwarding on your router. This will direct the internet traffic to your computer. You will need to get the exact instructions for your specific model of router.

Please be aware that you need to have proper firewalls and systems in place to prevent attacks. I am sure that you are just testing at this point though...

All the best!